# Ruby "FloatDomainError: Infinity" when calculating Fibonacci Number

Tags: ruby, range, fibonacci, infinite

My method for calculating the "length" of a fibonacci number (i.e. number of digits) fails after the 1474th iteration.  My way of obtaining the desired result is probably very clumsy, so please let me know if there is a flaw in my approach.  I suspect there is something rather wasteful in running a block method across an infinite range until it stumbles across the answer, but at this stage it's the best I've got.  I'd certainly like to do better though.

For numbers smaller than the one below, it works perfectly, until it gets to the 1474th number:

> 49922546054780146353198579531352153533212840109029466994098142197617303359523104269471455390562835412104406019654730583800904132982935807202575490044075132631203284854890505808877430837618493577512703453928379390874730829906652067545822236147772760444400628059249610784412153766674534014113720760876471943168

And thereafter returns this error:

```
FloatDomainError: Infinity
```

Here is how my method works:

First I use the standard formula for obtaining the "nth" number in a fibonacci sequence:

```
def fibonacci_index(n)
  ((1 / Math.sqrt(5)) * ((1 + Math.sqrt(5)) / 2) ** (n + 1)).round(0)
end
```

Then I convert the output to a string and measure its length:

```
def fibonacci_index_length(n)
  fibonacci_index(n).to_s.length
end
```

And then finally I create an **infinite range** and run a **block** method inside a **while loop**:

```
def find_fibonacci_index_by_length(integer)

  # Range to infinity because I don't want to
  # limit the size of the numbers I work with
  infinity = 1.0 / 0.0
  range = (1..infinity)

  # while loop to run through the range
  running = true

  while running
    range.each do |n|

      f_index = n + 1
      f_number = fibonacci_index(n)
      f_length = fibonacci_index_length(n)

      if fibonacci_index_length(n) == integer && fibonacci_index(n) != 1

        puts "f_index: #{f_index}"
        puts "f_number: #{f_number}"
        puts "f_length: #{f_length}"

        running = false

        # This breaks from the block
        return f_index

      elsif fibonacci_index_length(n) == integer && fibonacci_index(n) == 1

        running = false
        return 1

      else
        # puts "Still looking, number is #{fibonacci_index(n)}"
        puts "Still looking, Fibonacci index: #{f_index}"
        puts f_number
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ruby, as with any floating point system, there's a maximum value that can be expressed. You have a 308 digit number there and the max for floats is `Float::MAX` or `1.7976931348623157e+308`.

You'll need to do this with Integer math if you want to avoid that problem. Ruby's "bignum" system can handle arbitrary length numbers up to millions of places, but be aware performance does get to be pretty bad the bigger they get.

Here's an unoptimized replacement:

```
def fibonacci_index(n)
  a = [ 1, 1 ]

  while (a.length < n)
    a << (a[-1] + a[-2])
  end

  return a[-1]
end
```

It's worth noting that your Float-based calculation, as with anything to with floating point math, is an **approximation and not an exact value**. This is absolutely critical to remember whenever doing math with floating point values. This is fine for things like fluid dynamics simulations or 3D rendering where close enough counts. It is *not* fine for things like this where every digit counts, or monetary situations where precision errors could lead to thousands or millions of dollars in lost money.

Here's the number you computed compared to the one brute-forced with reliable integer math:

```
4992254605477767835147644879936483062623238506802202927705709236175156181701079...
4992254605478014635319857953135215353321284010902946699409814219761730335952310...
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You can see the two values diverge wildly.

Comment: What about Rational?

Comment: I've added a functional replacement, though you may want to optimize it using a cache or whatever you need to achieve whatever level of performance you require.

Comment: As you're not dealing with fractional values, Rational doesn't make sense here. That's for expressing things like `1/17` and `1/3` without losing precision.

Comment: Thanks! I took a bit of time to make sure I understand your answer, but it makes sense to me now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use integer arithmetic as it's capable of supporting infinite precision. You used floating point whose precision is limited.

To speed up computations I recommend that you cache the values of the sequence. The implementation can be as simple as:

```
class RecursiveFibonacci
  def initialize
    @cache = { 1 => 1, 2 => 2 }
  end

  def [](n)
    @cache[n] ||= self[n - 2] + self[n - 1]
  end
end

fibonacci = Fibonacci.new
fibonacci[6] #=> 13
```

You may add some error detection (for example raising an error when `n <= 0`). If you'd like to use an iterative algorithm then something like the following should work:

```
class IterativeFibonacci
  def [](n)
    # Add 1 to covert the index from zero-based to one-based.
    sequence.take(n + 1).last
  end

  private

  def sequence
    Enumerator.new do |yielder|
      a, b = 1, 1
      yielder << a
      loop do
        a, b = b, a + b
        yielder << a
      end
    end
  end
end
```

If you want to work with a slice of the sequence (say terms from 1 to 10,000) then I recommend you make `#sequence` public and take slice it to make the algorithm faster.

Comment: Nice work using `Enumerator`. That's a handy tool for situations like this. You could also combine the cached method with the Enumerator driven one to make it faster.